# Firefox can't dispatch and then refresh page but other browsers can

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, redux

I am using redux toolkit and I am dispatching a function using redux thunk. After I dispatch this particular function I was just forcing a page refresh (to trigger useEffects) instead of calling all the things I wanted to refresh manually as this function resets everything and it would be easier to just refresh the whole page. The problem I am running into is that in the firefox browser the following code just refreshes the page but the function never goes off:

```
  const resetPortfolioFunc = (e) => {
    dispatch(resetPortfolio());
    window.location.reload(false);
  };
```

I have also tried

```
  const resetPortfolioFunc = (e) => {
    dispatch(resetPortfolio());
    window.location = window.location;;
  };
```

And to clarify in brave, chrome, and microsoft edge the above code works perfectly as expected, it is merely Firefox that refreshes the page without dispatching the function and changing anything.

Just in case it is needed (which I do not think it is) here is the actual function resetPortfolio and the slice

```
export const resetPortfolio = createAsyncThunk(
  "/portfolio/resetPortfolio",
  async (value, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
    const userID = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user._id;
    const newObj = {
      token: token,
      userID: userID,
    };
    let url = `http://localhost:3001/api/portfolio/resetPortfolio`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, newObj);
    return response.data;
  }
);



export const portfolioSlice = createSlice({
  name: "portfolio",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(resetPortfolio.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.resetStatus = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(resetPortfolio.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.resetStatus = "success";
      })
      .addCase(resetPortfolio.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.resetStatus = "failed";
      });
  },
});
```

Now since I am using redux I do have a work around which is just to call window.location.reload(false) under a useEffect is the status is successful for the dispatch like:

```
 const resetPortfolioFunc = (e) => {
    dispatch(resetPortfolio());
  };

useEffect(() => {
 if (status == 'success') {
    window.location.reload
}
}, [status])
```

Now this solution is actually a bit slower than the original, which feels instant in all the browsers it works in for one, so if there is a way to get the original to work in firefox I would like to know if not I would at least like to know why firefox behaves this way when other browsers do not.

Comment: There's a  note under  `location.reload` [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload#syntax) about its boolean parameter on MDN.  Does it do what you want if you pass  `true` instead of `false` ?

Comment: @traktor 'false' or 'true' made no difference. The note you linked provided helpful insight however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so much about Redux - this is about you starting a network request and not waiting for it to actually happen.

Await the dispatch of the thunk (and such, the network request) before doing anything else.

```
  const resetPortfolioFunc = async (e) => {
    await dispatch(resetPortfolio());
    window.location.reload(false);
  };
```

Comment: Ah well this actually does work, I did go to try this but for whatever reason in vscode with the exact code above I get an underline error for await that states "await has not effect on this type of action", thus assumed you could not use it like that, however it works despite the error.

Comment: That means that your `dispatch` type does not know about the thunk middleware. Please make sure to set up correctly typed hooks as described in [the TypeScript QuickStart tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks)